# Setting Item column value to Approver Name from an Approval Task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, approval

I have a Library where each item uploaded creates an Approval Task.
When this is approved i want the columns "Approved By" and "Approved Date" to be updated to the person who approved the task and the time they did so...

I have been trying to get this to work by using the below under the 'Set X To Y' action but this seems to return the completely wrong name!

```
**Field Data to Retrieve**
Data Source = Association: Task List
Field from Source = Modified By
Return Field As = Display Name

**Find List Item**
Field: ID
Value: Current Item:ID
```

A few help topics online refer to using [%CurrentTask:Modified%] however this is not a visible option when i try to use this.

Any help appreciated as I was trying to get users to start using this today :(

Image of the action:
[image: Screenshot of action]

Comment: Are your sure that task item ID and library item ID are the same?

Comment: You are right.... they are not. How can i link them together to make sure i can pull the approver name from the correct task?

Comment: You need to store item's ID in task item or vice versa

Comment: Thanks. Is there a 'best suggested field' to do this in?

Comment: Look here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3a63c0f1-0545-4650-bd08-032cdf4180d1/find-current-task-and-reference-field-in-associated-task-list-of-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Task ID from the within the task behaviour. Click on **"Change the behaviour of a single task"**:
[image]

The best place to set the field in the list / library would probably be in the **"When a Task is Pending"**. You can add a "Set field in current item" action or if you wish to assign it to a workflow variable you can use the "Set Workflow Variable" action.

[image]
Then in the workflow use it like the following:

[image]

Links:

[Find current task and reference field in associated task list of workflow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3a63c0f1-0545-4650-bd08-032cdf4180d1/find-current-task-and-reference-field-in-associated-task-list-of-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomization)

[Capture task ID for approval task in SharePoint Designer 2010](http://riedoh.blogspot.com/2011/07/capture-task-id-for-approval-task.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont seem to have or be able to find the option to the screen where 'change the behaviour of a single task' is listed. I can find 'Task' or 'Workflow Task (SP 2013)' content types but the only option for either of these in the customization section is 'Edit Content Type Columns'. I suspect i may be in the wrong place but the screen looks the same. 

Sorry to be a pain, but cold you help get me to this screen.

Comment: If it helps the line in my workflow for the task is:
`Start a task process with Training Approver List:Approver(s) (Task outcome to Variable:Outcome)`

Comment: Click on `Approval(5)` in `start Approval(5) process on...` action on the screenshot above

Comment: Is `Approval(5)` a seperate workflow. as i only have `start a task process` but the `task process` bit isn't clickable.

Am i using the wrong type of action/task process?

Comment: What do you use? Site WF?

Comment: I'm using SPD2013 to create the workflow.
Believe it's a list/library workflow that i'm currently using.
Does that help?

Comment: What is platform type of your WF? 2010 or 2013? View it on WF properties page in SPD.

Comment: Please add a screenshot with your action.

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Comment: Doesnt load in comments - will add screenshot to original question

Comment: This did work in the end. I just needed to migrate it over to a SharePoint 2010 workflow as i didnt get these options in the 2013 platform. Thanks for your help!