# How to retrieve task id from "start a task process" action

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I have a SharePoint 2013 platform Workflow where i start an approval Task:

a) I currently use "Assign a task" action and use the Task Id return field to get approval comments from the task
b) I changed the action to "Start a task process" (more people involved), but it doesn´t return task id.

How can i get the value of the task id (approver)?
In alternative is there a workaround to get the comments (a field from the task list) from the approver?

regards,

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/243121/75974

Answer (score 0):

When using "Start a task Process" action, there is no OOB way to retrieve the task Id.

As a workaround, I suggest you use "Assign a task" action instead of "Start a task process".

Or you can switch to use SharePoint 2010 platform workflow instead of SharePoint 2013 platform workflow.

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242969/setting-item-column-value-to-approver-name-from-an-approval-task/243121#243121) for you.